# Another IE cache error... but with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, spring-mvc

I have a simple select list, you can add/remove names then save them.

Starting with a freshly empty cache, (tools->delete history) Say I 2 names on the list, add a name, click save.  I then reload, and I have 3 names.

I then remove a name, click save. I then reload and Have 3 names.

I empty cache and reload, and I have the 2 names I was supposed to have.

The problem is that IE is caching the jQuery call to get the list of names.

How do I stop this?  I have done some research and find that there are 2 options:

1. add a random number to the end of the call.  (This seems a TERRIBLE hack)
2. add Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=1 to every response.

I am wondering if there is a better solution.

Also I am using Spring 3.4 MVC,  is there a way to do #2 in a config file or something, rather than going through EVERY controller and EVERY method.

Thank You

Comment: GET requests cache, that is how the web works. If you do not want the browser to cache, you set the proper headers.

Comment: if by `jQuery call to get the list of names` you mean a jQuery AJAX request, you can specify `cache: false` as one of its options

Comment: which does #1 under the cover which the OP does not like.

Comment: I don't mind #1 if I'm the one who does not have to do it!  @scrowler - I am using the $get() but I can add that parameter.

Comment: @epascarello - I changed the reload to $post and that does seem to work.  Not sure what the "correct" way is.